# Is this scenario possible with stellar?

Tags: transactions, memo

another noob question :
Is it technically possible to use SSC for build a third party escrow service ?

Let's imagine an absurd scenario : Once upon a time a man named Jed. He want to sell his Nintendostation 128 for 1000 xlm.

He publish an announce on a consumer-to-consumer platform.

Joyce saw the announce and want to buy it.

The transaction scheme is then :

- Joyce send 1200 xlm to a new account generated by the
  consumer-to-consumer platform.
- A tx is generated by this new account, with a random-generated memo, and send to the stellar account of Jed.
- Jed send    his Nintendostation by a postal service to Joyce postal
  address, with the random-generated memo printed in the packet.
- One Joyce receveid    it, she send a tx to the consumer-to-consumer
  account with the    random-generated memo.
- The consumer-to-consumer account then send    1000 xlm to Jed and
  send back 199.9 lumens to Joyce.

The End.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start, much of the proposed above is based on trust rather than rules defined in an SSC. There are no measures preventing the consumer-to-consumer platform from just taking the money and leaving. I would recommend building a 3-Party SSC from some of the 2-Party SSC's available. In these examples, there are fail-safes in place that disincentive foul play.

Ultimately, this proposed scenario seems to be a derivation of the [2-Party Multisignature Escrow Account with Time Lock and Recovery](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/walkthroughs/stellar-smart-contracts.html#2-party-multisignature-escrow-account-with-time-lock-recovery) presented in the SSC docs from Stellar.org. In fact, this is actually very similar to a [Distributed Trustless Worker Smart Contract proposed by Zulu Crypto](https://medium.com/@zulucrypto_23845/distributed-trustless-workers-with-stellar-e197fd1b77f6).

In Zulu Crypto's smart contract, a customer is paying a worker for generating a vanity address (a computationally expensive problem). A very basic overview of how this works is:

1. Customer creates an escrow account with 1000 XLM.
2. Once the escrow account is funded, two transactions are created. The first transaction is a timebounded refund that will send the 1000 XLM back to the customer in case the exchange never takes place (this ensures the funds will not be lost). The second is a transaction that makes the escrow account *escrowy* aka the worker and customer are added as signers with weight 1, the thresholds of the escrow account are made weight 2 and the master key of the escrow is made weight 0.
3. Worker proves they have found such a vanity keypair.
4. The two create a transfer transaction where: 
   **a.** the worker sets the vanity account's signer to the customer, sets all the vanity's thresholds to 1 and sets the master key of the vanity account to 0 
   **b.** the user and the worker merge the escrow account to the worker so the worker gets paid.

Of course, a swap of physical goods would be a little more difficult. You would have to ensure that once the package is received, the payment is made. This may require some 3rd-party such as a delivery service, or a scannable barcode that activates the transfer transaction. Nevertheless, I imagine you could follow a similar pattern to the one outlined above. Maybe instead of a 2-of-2 multisignature, you could create a 2-of-3 where the 3rd party acts as an oracle.

What is an oracle? Here are some good reads:

- https://medium.com/bethereum/how-oracles-connect-smart-contracts-to-the-real-world-a56d3ed6a507
- https://medium.com/@mustwin/building-an-oracle-for-an-ethereum-contract-6096d3e39551
- https://blockchainhub.net/blockchain-oracles/

**tldr: I believe it is possible and a good starting ground may be to experiment with and build off of some of the already existing 2-party SSC's.**